# Add custom columns to Woocommerce customers table

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

By clicking woocommerce->customers i can get a table of all of the customers.
Is there a way to add columns to it? I found that there is a manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns, but i can't find the customers post type.

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce is not using wordpress tables structure.
this is easily visible by comparing `woocommerce->customers` table with `users->All Users`
[manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_screen-id_columns/) is defenetly not the filter you're looking for.
the columns are located in this path:
[`packages/woocommerce-admin/src/API/Reports/Customers/Controller.php`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-packages-woocommerce-admin-src-api-reports-customers-controller.html).
and the filter to change them is: `woocommerce_report_customers_export_columns`